# Converter estrutura de dados em JSON em Objeto

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, webforms

Estou utilizando o framework [Materializecss - autocomplete](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#autocomplete), e gostaria de alimentar um campo autocomplete com dados vindos de minha base. O autocomplete trabalha com dados na seguinte estrutura de objetos:

```
{
  "Apple": null,
  "Microsoft": null,
  "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
}
```

E meus dados são exportados na estrutura JSON válida abaixo (os dados são dinâmicos):

```
[{
 "Apple": null
 },
 {
 "Microsoft": null
 },
 {
 "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
}]
```

Assim, como faço para converter essa minha estrutura JSON válida na estrutura utilizada pelo autocomplete?

Mas, se alguém souber fazer o autocomplete funcionar com esse JSON válido, melhor ainda.

Estou utilizando php, jquery e mysql

Desde já agradeço a colaboração.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido!

Pessoal consegui exportar minha estrutura JSON em uma estrutura JSON simples.

```
$list = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
   $data[$value->nome]  = null;    
} 

return json_encode($data,  true);
```

Exportou exatamente a seguinte estrutura:

```
{
 "Apple": null,
 "Microsoft": null,
 "Google": null
}
```